# What is a good ASP.NET Ad Server?

Tags: asp.net, ads, adsense

I'm looking for a good ad server that will run on ASP.NET. OpenX is great because it's open source but it's only for PHP.

I found this: http://www.adserverbeans.com/
but it runs on Flex which i've never used. Would that work on an IIS server?

Any good asp.net ad servers out there?

Answer (score 3):

How about [BanManPro](http://www.banmanpro.com/) ? (If I'm not mistaken, StackOverflow uses them)

> BanManPro Ad Serving Software for .NET/Windows Servers

Personally I have never tried it, but I think it's worth a look.

---

There is also [Absolute Banner Manager .NET](http://www.xigla.com/absolutebmnet/index.htm) :

> Absolute Banner Manager .NET is a
>   feature-packed Ad Tracking and Banner
>   Management software specially
>   developed for the webmaster looking
>   for a scalable, flexible and reliable
>   Banner Ad Serving front-end tool.

---

But you can still run OpenX on IIS if you have `php` set up.
Here are a couple of links to get your started on setting up PHP on IIS :

- http://php.iis.net/
- http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2006/09/19/How-to-install-PHP-on-IIS7-_2800_RC1_2900_.aspx

Also, if you want to try Flex on IIS, here's a link to a module for Apache and IIS : http://labs.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/Flex_Module_for_Apache_and_IIS

Comment: BanManPro is nice, but last I checked, too pricey.  Especially considering all the free alternatives

Comment: BanManPro is about $1000 last I heard. Well worth the money considering that is probably less than one month's worth of ad sales.

Answer (score 1):

You can run OpenX on IIS if you install PHP on the server and set it up right.  I've used it before (back when it was phpAdsNew) and it ran very well in this environment.  I've used a .NET ad server before but it was very expensive ($1k+) and really did the same thing as OpenX.

Answer (score 1):

I use Agile AdNET and it's very simple to use. It's quite easy in respect to manage ads

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Agile AdNet is good tool for online advertisement. very easy to use, no need to get bothered about technical things easy reports. Online report status updates.

On one go every one can understand and use it.
Simple flow is the beauty of the product.

Answer (score 0):

> I found this: http://www.adserverbeans.com/ but it runs on Flex which i've never used. Would that work on an IIS server?

Yes, it would. As the lead developer on ASB MyAds project I hereby confirm that our product can run on any major platform (Windows, UNIX, Mac) with  any HTTP server in the front. We are starting our own HTTP server though (Winstone/Tomcat servlet container written in Java) , so you can use IIS to proxy requests to the servlet container running on port 8080 eg.
You can't use IIS to interprete jsp / run Java servlets, right?

ActionScript 3.0 (Flex) is an object oriented language with syntax similar to that of Java and C#. Compilation/development is also platform-independent.

> Also, if you want to try Flex on IIS, here's a link to a module for Apache and IIS : www.labs.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/Flex_Module_for_Apache_and_IIS

Not with ASB MyAds. We compile our swf file separately, package it and load it at one fell swoop into the browser.
This module for IIS obviously allows on the fly compilation of MXML files similar to the way JSP, php, asp files are interpreted/compiled by corresponding server technologies.

Answer (score -1):

I have been working on various websites for different technologies. I found AGILE AdNET the most easy, affordable ad server solutions till date.
http://www.agileoutsource.com/products/adnet.html